# Modal for emojis not working correctly in Angular

Tags: angular, emoji

I am trying to add emoji functionality on my chatting website but unfortunately, the emoji modal is not working correctly.
The code I did stands below.

```
- import module
import { PickerModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart';

- add emoji part on the html
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isBlocked">
        <textarea class="w-100 h-100 m-0 border-0" (blur)="onBlur()" (focus)="onFocus()" [(ngModel)]="message" rows="3" cols="50" formControlName="message_content"></textarea>
        <button (click) ="toggleEmojiPicker()"> </button><br>
        <emoji-mart class="emoji-mart" set="{{set}}" *ngIf="showEmojiPicker" (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)" title="Pick your emoji…"></emoji-mart>
    </ng-container>
```

The project runs completely but when I click  , the emoji dialog launch like below.
Please let me know how can I fix this issue.
[image]

Comment: what is it suppose to do?

Comment: @Maddy I hope the emoji dialog not mingling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for bothering your, @Maddy
I have missed importing CSS.

```
@import '~@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker';
```

I typed this command line in style.css and it works fine.